ASP.NET Core Web API : extract Swagger in Azure Devops pipeline
I have an ASP.NET Core Web API and I build it in Azure Devops Pipeline. Once buildt, I want to extract the swagger.json.
The problem is that the command in question tries I feel like launching the API, which I don't want because it won't find all the configuration like access to the bdd. ^
How to extract the swagger.json file without launching the API?
I need the swagger.json file because I use Azure APIM and therefore need to go update the swagger in
  cd $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/src/Api/bin/Release/net8.0/
  ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Local 
  dotnet swagger tofile --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/swagger.json $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/src/Api/bin/Release/net8.0/myApi.dll v1


As far as I tested with method from Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger, dotnet swagger tofile or curl commands to extract the swagger.json file, they all required to launch the API file first, no matter in local build environment or via Azure Pipelines. It seemed that the file was exported from the swagger url defined in the launchSettings. Here is my pipeline to generate the swagger.json file after dotnet build.
parameters:
- name: configuration
  default: Release
  values:
  - Debug
  - Release

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '**/*.sln'
    arguments: '--configuration ${{ parameters.configuration }} --verbosity detailed'
- script: |
    dotnet new tool-manifest
    dotnet tool install --version 6.5.0 Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli
    dotnet swagger tofile --help
    dotnet swagger tofile --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/swagger.json $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/ASPDotNetCoreWebApiDemo/bin/${{ parameters.configuration }}/net8.0/ASPDotNetCoreWebApiDemo.dll v1
    tree $(Pipeline.Workspace)
- publish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
  artifact: swagger


From the troubleshooting perspective of Azure DevOps, you may figure out the working command in local build environment before integrating the workflow in pipelines, which is also helpful for issue isolation.

I don’t understand your answer? Can I have an example

Hi there, I have updated the answer with a sample pipeline to extract swagger.json.

If I understand, will it launch the api? CAr this is my concern I do not want it to launch the api because it contains config that will not work on a pipeline

Yes, it will launch the api I think. So, your main concern is how to generate the swagger.json file without launching API, right? It seems to me that the question is more relevant to swagger rather than Azure DevOps. You may reach out to the swagger section for an answer to the specific question.

Yes it launches the api and I don’t want or I want as part of an azure devops pipeline, it continues even if I have exceptions related to database configuration or others

I am not sure if it is possible to extract the swagger.json file without launching the api. As far as I tested, I could only get this file when the api web app was running no matter from local environment or pipeline. I am not so familiar with swagger as devops. Hopefully, some specialists on swagger may share some insights, since Azure Pipelines are only automation tool.

Can it also be an option to just deploy the solution first to a DEV environment (in AKS, App Service, or whatever) and then create a new pipeline that (1) gets the OAS file in the Swagger URL and (2) implement the publishing pipeline of API Ops?
